# text overriding on another text, need to display below

Tags: html, css

please visit [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html) search for "check" using CTRL + F you can see :

[image]

please enter "110001" zip code in text field and click on "check" button,

[image]

you can see "`Selling Price + Rs. 30 Delivery`" text displaying, its fine.

than visit [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html) , you can see

[image]

than click on "check" button, you can see the same text below : "`Selling Price + Rs. 30 Delivery`" but its crossing "RS 500". so i want to display the  text bit below as in link1.

i am trying chnaging values in following code , but its affecting in other link :

```
.vship1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
```

please help me to display the text in same places in both links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote an inline style on you website only(inspect element)

```
<p class="vship1" style="margin-top:30px">
                                  Selling Price + <span class="price">Rs. 30</span> Delivery                                 </p>
```

and its working fine.

[image]

Comment: it work for link2 , but text will display below in link1.

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed.

Comment: i want to display the text in link2 as like link1.

Comment: I am not getting, how you want it to be displayed, btw you can change the margin value to adjust it there.

Comment: i edited my code as your answer, now please check link 1, text is displaying below. please help me to display above without affecting to link2.

Comment: i tried , but its varying in different links, if it work for link1, its not working for link2 and same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107856/discussion-between-viveksinghggits-and-profile-101).

Comment: Probably this happens because the second product has a "Special Price" if you have any control in your server code you could add a modifier class in a parent element and style it using this class.

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545936/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Answer (score 1):

Try cascade:

```
.block-content .vship1 {
    top: 140px;
}
```